# Getting characters from current position to end of line as a substring

Tags: buffers, string

Is there a standard Elisp function which can return as a substring (without any of the text-properties) the characters from the current position of point to the last nonwhite space character on that line.

For instance if the line is `Hello World` and the point is on `W` it should return `orld`  .

Note in particular, if the line contains at least one non-whitespace character, I want everything ***only*** upto the last non-whitespace character.

If a line is blank or contains only white space characters I would like the function to return `nil`

Comment: @ Drew Fixed! Meant to say last non-white space character

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't believe there is a standard elisp function to do exactly what you ask, but it isn't hard to compose your own.  Here is my stab at what you describe:

```
(defun gw-string-to-end-of-line ()
  "Return a string from the current point to the end of line.

If there are white-space characters at the end of the line, they
will be stripped off.  If the string that would be returned would
be blank, nil is returned."
  (interactive)
  (let ((s (string-trim-right               ;; strip off any trailing
                                            ;; white space
            (buffer-substring-no-properties ;; get the text from the
                                            ;; current position to the
                                            ;; end of the line
             (point) (point-at-eol)))))
    (unless (string-blank-p s)          ;; only return the string if
                                        ;; it contains something     other
                                        ;; than white space (otherwise
                                        ;; nil will be returned)
      s)))
```